# How to add a sublist to a sublist?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, comparison, sublist

I want to append a sublist to the previous sublist under certain circumstances, i.e. if its length is less than 2. So, the length of `[5]` less than 2 and now the previous list is to be extended with the 5 (a+b).

```py
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [5]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [1,1,1,1,1]
e = [1,2]
f = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

L = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

print 'List:', L

def short(lists):
    result = []
    for value in lists:
        if len(value) <= 2 and result:
            result[-1] = result[-1] + value
    return result

result = short(L)
print 'Result:', result
```

The result should be: `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]`

But from my code, I get: `[]`

Comment: You have `and result` in your condition. Your `result` list starts empty, so this condition starts out false, and it prevents anything getting added to `result`, so the condition will never pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

**Ex:**

```
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [5]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [1,1,1,1,1]
e = [1,2]
f = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

L = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

print( 'List:', L)

def short(lists):
    result = []
    for value in lists:
        if len(value) <= 2:            #check len
            result[-1].extend(value)   #extend to previous list
        else:
            result.append(value)       #append list. 
    return result

result = short(L)
print( 'Result:', result)
```

**Output:**

```
List: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [5], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
Result: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: If the first list is too short, it will fail, unless you add `and result` condition

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
def short(lists):
result = []
for value in lists:
    if len(value) < 2 and result:
        result[-1].extend(value)
    else:
        result.append(value)
return result
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw your comment and changed it!